# Get First and Last row based on timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I am trying to get the first and last rows for a certain individual based on timestamps. Below is the sample data

```
DATE        TIME             NAME       PAUSE CODE
2020-09-01  17:05:34         Name 1     LOGIN
2020-09-01  15:30:21         Name 1     LOGIN
2020-09-01  09:01:16         Name 1     LOGIN
2020-09-01  18:03:55         Name 2     LOGIN
2020-09-01  17:03:55         Name 2     LOGIN
2020-09-01  13:03:55         Name 2     LOGIN
2020-09-01  11:03:55         Name 2     LOGIN
2020-09-01  10:25:14         Name 2     LOGIN
```

For the above example the expected results would be like

```
DATE           NAME       TIME1            TIME2
2020-09-01     Name 1     09:01:16         17:05:34
2020-09-01     Name 2     10:25:14         18:03:55
```

Not sure how to do this in Pandas. Hopefully someone can shed light on this.

Comment: cant u do min and max on date/time row to get the first and last row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I group max and min timestamp on pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666085/how-do-i-group-max-and-min-timestamp-on-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get your results

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['DATE','NAME'])
                    .agg({'TIME':['min','max']})
                    .rename(columns={'min':'TIME1','max':'TIME2'})).reset_index()
print (df)
```

OR:

```
df = (df.groupby(['DATE','NAME'])
                    .agg({'TIME':['min','max']})
                    .rename(columns={'min':'TIME1','max':'TIME2'})).reset_index()

print (df)
```

This will result in

```
         DATE    NAME      TIME          
                          TIME1     TIME2
0  2020-09-01  Name 1  09:01:16  17:05:34
1  2020-09-01  Name 2  10:25:14  18:03:55
```

You can also get the same thing done as follows:

```
df = df.groupby(['DATE','NAME']).agg(TIME1=pd.NamedAgg(column='TIME', aggfunc='min'),
                            TIME2=pd.NamedAgg(column='TIME', aggfunc='max'))

print (df)
```

Output will be:

```
                      TIME1     TIME2
DATE       NAME                      
2020-09-01 Name 1  09:01:16  17:05:34
           Name 2  10:25:14  18:03:55
```

Comment: The last suggestion accomplished what I was intending to do. Thanks!

Comment: If this solved your problem, please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.